# In my output I want unique customer ID with customer name

Tags: python, pandas

[image][image]In my output I want unique customer ID with customer name. Is that possible? (both 'Customer ID' and 'Customer Name' in my data frame)
In output I am getting only the 'Customer ID' but I want Customer name as well.

[df3['Customer ID'].unique()]['Customer Name']

Comment: Please provide sample from your data, ideally through pasting ```df3.to_dict()``` and show what kind of output you expect. 

Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @the_pr0blem I have added the picture of my data

Comment: Without expected output I cannot be sure if this helps, but you can try this: 
```unique_customers = df3[["Customer ID", "Customer Name"]].drop_duplicates()```

Comment: @the_pr0blem Updated, please check.

Comment: Check this: ```df3[df3['Status'] == "Returned"][["Customer ID", "Customer Name"]].drop_duplicates()```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pandas expert but this might help:

1. Im interpreting your question as asking for a table containing customer IDs and their associated customer Name. Where no two customer ID's are duplicated.

First you can winnow down the table with this line

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["Customer ID"])
```

At this point df will contain the first occurence of each unique customer ID and all the associated information in the other columns of these rows.

Then you can grab just the first two columns `Customer ID` and `Customer Name` by slicing. This looks like

```
df.loc[:["Customer ID","Customer Name"]]
```

As I said Im no pandas expert, there are likely better ways but this should get the job done.

As a note you may want to make copies of your dataframe and do these operations on the copies so as to not loose your original data if you wish to do further operations.